# ClickHouse CAST column AS SIGNED?

Tags: clickhouse

I have a table with column that contains timezone in format: +00:00
eg.:

| tz |
| --- |
| +04:30 |
| +02:00 |
| +10:00 |
| -04:00 |

I can use CAST in MySQL: `CAST(tz AS SIGNED)` and it will give this result:

| CAST(tz AS SIGNED) |
| --- |
| 4 |
| 2 |
| 10 |
| -4 |

I tried to use `toInt64` for ClickHouse, but it produce an exception.
How I can reach the same result with ClickHouse ?

Comment: Why 04:30 become 4 ?

Comment: SIGNED `Produces a signed BIGINT value` : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast

Comment: I see. It's a special case in mysql for intervals with TZ. There is no such feature in CH. You need to parse Strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT
    arrayJoin(['+04:30', '-4:30', '10:00']) AS x,
    toInt64OrZero(extract(x, '(.*):')) AS y

Query id: 4b704281-649a-499e-906c-89873112c9e1

┌─x──────┬──y─┐
│ +04:30 │  4 │
│ -4:30  │ -4 │
│ 10:00  │ 10 │
└────────┴────┘
```